# Can't get dynamic table elements value using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, find, element, dynamic-tables

I want to get the values of a dynamic created table but I couldn't figure out what is wrong.

the table created in a php file or it creates in server side by calling it in jquery.

for making it clear : in my html page I run a jquery method to load this table.

then I need this table values to be able to edit them. but what I get instead of the element value is undefined. (when I alert the value)

this is the jquery code :

```
//<!-- ajax Post Request -->
$(function() {
    $('#edit_test_show').hide();
    $('#save_edit').hide();
    var vop_id = localStorage.getItem('op_id');
    $.post("Requests/OPS.php", //Required URL of the page on server
        { // Data Sending With Request To Server
            read_OPS: true,
            op_id: vop_id
        },
        function(response) { // Required Callback Function
            if (response) {
                $("#result_table").html(response);
            }
        });
    //====================
    $('#enable_edit').on('click', function() {
        $('#edit_test_show').show();
        $('#enable_edit').hide();
        $('#save_edit').show();
    });
    $('#save_edit').on('click', function() {
        $('#edit_test_show').hide();
        $('#enable_edit').show();
        $('#save_edit').hide();
        var vop_id = localStorage.getItem('op_id');
        var vop_title = $('#result_table').find('#op_title').val();
        var vop_descrip = $('#result_table').find('#op_descrip').val();
        alert(vop_title);
    });
});
```

html part which the table loads in :

```
 <form  method='post' class="form-inline">
       <div class="form-group">
         <div id="result_table">
          <!--  dynamic op load -->
         </div>
       </div>
 </form>
<button type='button' id="enable_edit" class='btn btn-default'>edit</button>
<button type='button' id="save_edit" class='btn btn-default'>save</button>
```

and this is the php code which generate the table :

```
if($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($read_op)) {
    echo "
    <table class='styled-table' cellspacing='0' width='360' border='1' >
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for='mail_num' style='margin-right:10px;color:#595959;float: right;'>شماره فرآیند : </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name='op_id'  style='width:240px;height: 25px;margin:0 3px 0 3px;'
                value='".$row['id']."'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for='op_title' style='margin-right:10px;color:#595959;float: right;'>عنوان فرآیند  : </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name='op_title'  style='width:240px;height: 25px;margin:0 3px 0 3px;'
                value='".$row['op_title']."'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for='op_descrip' style='margin-right:10px;color:#595959;float: right;'>شرح فرآیند : </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea name='op_descrip' class='textarea_2' rows='0' cols='0' >".$row['op_descrip']."</textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class='cleaner h20'></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [ID Selector (“#id”)](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) but not defined ID in HTMl thus you are not able to find element

*Define the IDs as*

```
<input id='op_id' value='".$row['id']."'/>
```

OR, Use [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

```
var vop_title = $('#result_table').find('[name=op_title]').val();
var vop_descrip = $('#result_table').find('[name=op_descrip]').val();
```

Comment: thanks for response , sorry my bad. i didn't notice that.